# INFINITY in Swift Lang

Tags: swift, infinity

According to Apple's documentation, Swift doesn't support preprocessor directives. In C/Objective-c the "INFINITY" definition is very useful for some checks. 
So, How do I get a number that never is less that another?

Comment: You could try dividing the float one by the float zero.

Comment: @Pascal: That probably gets you the float NaN. Or a crash.

Comment: @rickster I believe that the folk at Apple are a little more familiar with IEEE 754 than that.

Comment: @rickster, dividing by zero triggers an exception only with integer division. Edge case floating-point divisions are well-defined and do not cause CPU exceptions.

Comment: Swift does not support preprocessor directives, but thanks to the module implementation, Swift doesn't have to parse header files to have access to all what's inside. In fact, Swift *does* [translate simple macro values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_22) into global variables. I don't have access to the compiler, but have you tried simply using `INFINITY`?

Comment: @zneak I tried, but Xcode throw a error message "Use of unresolved identifier". Anyway, I am checking the "Simple Macros", that's very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Using INFINITY directly results in an unresolved symbol error. I am using this homegrown formulae for dealing with 64-bit Doubles: unsafeBitCast(0x7ff << 52, Double.self)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is already buildin infinity and also a check function. And you could also directly compare them with <.

```
var infinity = Double.infinity
var isInfinite = infinity.isInfinite
var someDouble = 234432.0
if someDouble < infinity {
    println("Less than")
} else {
    println("Small than")
}
// And the answer is Less than.
```

Answer (score 13):

For integer values, you should use `Int.max`.

```
var highestNumber = Int.max

//if you need negative infinity
var lowestNumber = Int.min
```

Using `NSIntegerMax` instead of `Int.max` or `-1 * NSIntegerMax` instead of `Int.min` is equivalent, but less pretty. (Thanks @Charlesism)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `finite`, for example,

```
let x:CDouble = 0.1
finite(x) // which return a CInt
```

Answer (score 0):

For Float values,

```
import UIKit

typealias Space = Float

var MaxSpaceSize = Space.infinity

var space:Space = 1100

space = space * 2
```